# Cmake could not find boost (iostreams)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've installed boost_1_67_0 from the source using the steps

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$HOME/boost_1_67_0
$ ./b2 install
```

As per the documentation of boost, that should install all of the boost libraries.

Now I am trying to install a software called dolfin, which requires boost, using cmake but I am getting the following error.

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/fenics/dolfin -Dpybind11_DIR=$HOME/fenics/pybind11 -DBOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/boost_1_67_0/include -DBOOST_LIBRARY_DIR=$HOME/boost_1_67_0/lib -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=$HOME/fenics/Eigen3/include ..

CMake Error at /opt/ohpc/pub/utils/cmake/3.15.4/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: iostreams) (found version "1.67.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ohpc/pub/utils/cmake/3.15.4/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/ohpc/pub/utils/cmake/3.15.4/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2161 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:269 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I can see the header files in $HOME/boost_1_67_0/include/boost/iostreams and the libraries in $HOME/boost_1_67_0/lib

```
$ ls $HOME/boost_1_67_0/lib | grep iostreams
libboost_iostreams.a
libboost_iostreams.so -> libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0
libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0
```

The naming convention of this particular library is not different from any of the other libraries in that directory. I've tried multiple different versions of boost with the exact same result. I am at my wit's end as to why cmake is complaining about not being able to find just that one library.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can fix this? Thank you very much for any help I can get!

Comment: To the `cmake <...>` call add option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`, which will print exact Boost files which are searched. Compare these files with ones you actually have.

Comment: Thank you for that very helpful tip. It turns out cmake had memorized some settings from earlier failed run attempts and was using those. I deleted all the old files in the build directory and ran it again. It was able to find all the boost libraries.